# Why can't I get credit for some of the Kerrigan achievements in the HotS campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've gotten most of the different achievements from the Kerrigan sub-group of the Heart of the Swarm campaign achievements, the ones for using the various abilities Kerrigan gets. But some of the ones I haven't gotten are for some of the first achievements you get.

At first I couldn't figure out why, then I looked at the achievements, recorded their progress, used the associated abilities a *lot* in a mission, then checked them again. No change. So I tried swapping to some other abilities for a mission or two then swapping back. Nothing. I finished the campaign and tried using them in the Master Archives. No progress. I gave up and restarted the campaign from the beginning. *Still* no progress.

Is there anything else I can try? Has Blizzard said anything about this issue?

Edit: Oops, forgot to mention the specific achievements. The ones that won't update for me are **Smoking Corpses**, **Get a Grip**, and **So Many Banelings!**

Comment: Could you please list the specific achievements that are not updating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In several threads ([1](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/6893511534), [2](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/6892700358), [3](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/6893981114)) on B.net Tech Support forums, people say that those achievements have to be done **in a single mission**. Blizzard has [acknowledged](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2267599524#2) this as a bug too.

Affected achievements include everything from **Swarm Campaign** / **Kerrigan** category that requires to use X skill Y times.

- **Smoking Corpses** - kill 50 units/structures with Kinetic Blast
- **Leaping Death** - deal 15000 damage with Leaping Strike
- **Get a Grip** - hit 150 enemies with Crushing Grip
- **Unchained** - deal 5000 damage with Chain Reaction
- **Shifted Priorities** - deal 5000 damage with Psionic Shift
- **So Many Banelings!** - kill 100 units with Spawn Banelings
- **Worker Rush** - morph 36 pairs of Twin Drones

The following achievements I *personally* did not have problems with, and they *may* be cumulative over missions. If anyone can confirm, please do.

- **Endless Swarm** - reconstitute 500 zerglings
- **Where The Wild Things Are** - hit 100 units with Wild Mutation
- **Surprise!** - kill 100 units with Infest Broodlings active

The rest of Kerrigan achievements directly state the requirement "in a single mission".

Comment: It is 2:20 AM, and I can firsthandedly confirm those achievements are attainable by farming on Casual. Why am I such an achievement, ehm, girl, I need to work tomorrow...

Answer (score 3):

Blizzard had the achievement system down for a bit the day of the release.  For whole campaign things (example, level 80) must be done again in a brand new campaign.

In just a one level/game achievement you should be able to get it.

Comment: How anything in this post relates to Kerrigan achievement category? =)

Comment: I know personally, I had a few Kerrigan Achievements that occurred while the server was down and didn't get credit for it.  Idk, maybe he meant that?

Comment: @Falcon165o Some achievements can indeed get broken or get unknown requirements, like "Normal/Hard/Brutal: 20". But Kerrigan's do work in an obvious way (barring this single mission issue).

Comment: I am currently at like 19th mission on Brutal so far but I'm now just triggering 15... because the first 4 was when the achievement server was down... I'm sure after playing the first 4 missions again I will get full credit and my 20 brutal :)

Answer (score 3):

Many of Kerrigan's Achievements are [bugged](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2267599524).  Scroll down to points one and three in the Heart of the Swarm section of the linked known issues list.

> Most of Kerrigan's achievements restart tracking progress when playing across multiple missions.
>   We are currently investigating this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Those achievements have to be completed in single mission even if this is not stated directly. Had the same issue and it works.
Best regards,